# Random number generator w/ button

Tags: javascript, html, button

Basically I have this.. but I want the BUTTON to generate the random number.. which currently only happens when I run the html file, which I don't want that to happen. Thanks!

```
<body>
<form name="rn">
      <input type="text" id="tb" name="tb" /></br>


    <input type="button" value="Random Number!" onclick="doFunction(Random);" />
</form>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function Random() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000);
    }




    document.getElementById('tb').value = Random()
</script>
```

Comment: The previos answer that is now deleted actually did work.

Comment: What is it that you expect `doFunction` to do?

Comment: @Xufox It didn't. I tried it out myself. Also I did not even delete the answer.

Comment: Nobody said that _you_ deleted the answer. You don’t even have the privilege to delete others’ posts. Anyway, you only _now_ edited your question to specify that you didn’t want the random number to be generated on page load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your HTML to this

```
<form name="rn">
    <input type="text" id="tb" name="tb" />
    <input type="button" value="Random Number!" onclick="Random();" />
</form>
```

and your javascript to this

```
function Random() {
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000);
        document.getElementById('tb').value = rnd;
    }
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/drgd5avx/)

Answer (score 1):

Put the code that sets `.value` in a function, and call that from the `onclick`

```js
function Random() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000);
}

function randomValue() {
  document.getElementById('tb').value = Random();
}
```

```html
<form name="rn">
  <input type="text" id="tb" name="tb" />
  </br>

  <input type="button" value="Random Number!" onclick="randomValue();" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is firing this on page load:

```
document.getElementById('tb').value = Random()
```

To prevent that from happening, wrap it the onclick function thike this:

```
function doFunction(){
document.getElementById('tb').value = Random()
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t33rdra6/1/